# Is set on lower-limit topology path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

Is $\mathbb R$ endowed with the left-hand topology (also called lower limit topology) path-connected?

Intuitively, I know that the answer is yes but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Would it suffice to say that a basic open set in $\mathbb R_\ell$ is of the form $[a,b)\in \mathbb R$ and is homeomorphic to I=[0,1]? Therefore any open set in $\mathbb R_\ell$ is path-connected?

Comment: how do you prove $[0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?? :O

Comment: $[0,\infty)\cup (-\infty, 0)$ is a separation of $\mathbb{R}_\ell$, see Arthur Fischer's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower-limit topology is not connected, and even satisfies the stronger "disconnectivity" property of *zero dimensionality*, meaning that it has a base consisting of clopen (closed and open) sets. For $a  <b$ we have $$\mathbb{R} \setminus [a, b) = ( - \infty, a) \cup [b,\infty)$$ which can easily be seen to be open in this topology.

Because it is not connected, it cannot be path-connected, as if there is a path between two points, those two points must belong to the same connected component of the space.

Comment: @PKStyles, I have expanded my answer to include more details.